# Built-in tree view for Django-Admin sites?

Tags: python, django, tree, view

Why is there no built-in tree view in the Python Django framework?
Isn't there an easy way to visualize a model when a class has an 1:n relation to itself?

I know about some fancy google code projects to achieve that but I think there must be some common sense among the Django community to handle this common case. Any ideas?

Comment: There are multiple ways to represent trees in a database. [Django Treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.61/) covers three of them (adjacency list, materialized path, and nested sets).

Answer (score 2):

The core devs are pretty strongly against adding extra stuff to Django unless there's a clear universal requirement - especially if there are perfectly good third-party projects that provide this functionality.

This is absolutely the case with tree views. It's very far from something that everyone wants to do, and there are at least three projects that provide trees, including the relevant tools to build representations of the trees in views and the admin.

I suggest you look into them - my favourite is [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a prove of concept application for Django - [django-admirarchy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admirarchy). It renders hierachies level by level (like Norton Commander and Co).

Answer (score 1):

**you can use django-mptt-admin**
The django-mptt app comes with a simple model administration mixin that allows you to create the tree structure and list it with indentation. To reorder trees, you need to either create this functionality yourself or use a third-party solution. Currently, there are two apps that can help you to create a draggable administration interface for hierarchical models. One of them is django-mptt-admin. Let's take a look at it in this recipe.

First, we need to have the django-mptt-admin app installed by performing the following steps:

```
(myproject_env)$ pip install django-mptt-admin
```

Then, put it in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings, as follows:

```
# conf/base.py or settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (



   # ...
    "django_mptt_admin"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

check out:

[tree structure of parent child relation in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229508/tree-structure-of-parent-child-relation-in-django-templates)

http://code.google.com/p/django-treeview/

An alternative would be to implement your tree in JavaScript. Django and JavaScript play nicely so that could work fine. There are plenty of JavaScript trees out there, just ask google

Answer (score 0):

[django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) is a really nice Django App for managing, sorting, and rendering tree data in templates easily. It solved my problem where I want to make a lean CMS and I need to manage my menus and categories. And it's really easy to install and well documented compared to other projects. It's an old project but still works perfectly on the latest Django version. As of this writing, I have used and tested it on Django 3.0.7 in Python 3.8