# tree structure of parent child relation in django templates

Tags: django, treeview, django-templates

how do i implement the tree structure in django templates with out using django-mptt.

i have model.

```
class Person(TimeStampedModel):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

now i want ..

```
 Parent
    Child 1
         subchild 1.1
         subchild 1.2
             nextsubchild 1.2.1
    Child 2
    Child 3
```

there names should be click able to show their profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from [Django while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408854/django-while-loop) question and

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

```
# view.py

@register.inclusion_tag('children.html')
def children_tag(person):
    children = person.children.all()
    return {'children': children}

# children.html

<ul>
    {% for child in children %}
    <li> <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child }}</a></li>
        {% if child.children.count > 0 %}
        {% children_tag child %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


# your template

{% children_tag parent %}
```

Comment: error occurred "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object", can you help me now?

Comment: i think include in for loop creating problem, otherwise code is so good.

Comment: Sorry i can't remember off the top of my head how i got around the recursion loop. I'll try to come back and edit this answer as soon as i find it in my code in the morning. Sorry Ahsan. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408854/django-while-loop looks like it may be of interest to you. They use an inclusion tag that includes itself.

Comment: @Ahsan glad you got it working. I was afraid i had led you astray =)

Comment: no no sir ... you guide me in right direction ... and i did it before your editing the answer :)

Comment: Shouldn't "children_list" be "children_tag" in the children.html?

Comment: It should. I was thinking over 20 mins, what is going on here, and finally I decided to copy paste and change `children_list` to `children_tag`. And it works, thanks! Finally I know how to template_tags works.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more!

Comment: Can you please add model, views, template step by step. I am not getting it.

Answer (score 13):

I just finished implementing this. I wanted a tree structure for a sub-navigation, but I did not want to do anything strange with recursive templates.

The solution I implemented is very simple: I simply recurse in the view (in my case a generic helper function) and flatten out the hierarchical structure into a simple list. Then, in my template I just use a for loop to iterate over the list.

Each element in the list can be one of three things: "in", the object, or "out". In my case, I'm constructing a series of ul li elements in the view, so when I encounter "in" I create a new ul, when I encounter "out" I close the ul. Otherwise, I render the item.

My template code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in sub_nav %}     
        {% if item == "in" %}         
            <ul>
        {% else %}
            {% if item == "out" %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href='{{item.full_url}}'>{{item.name}}</a>
                    {% if item.leaf %}
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The code in the helper function looks like this:

```
def get_category_nav(request,categories=None):
    """Recursively build a list of product categories. The resulting list is meant to be iterated over in a view"""
    if categories is None:
        #get the root categories
        categories = ProductCategory.objects.filter(parent=None)
        categories[0].active=True
    else:
        yield 'in'

    for category in categories:
        yield category
        subcats = ProductCategory.objects.select_related().filter(parent=category)
        if len(subcats):
            category.leaf=False
            for x in get_category_nav(request,subcats):
                yield x
        else:
            category.leaf=True
    yield 'out'
```

Using those snippets, you should be able to build any sort of hierarchical tree you'd like without doing any recursion in the template, and keeping all the logic in the view.

I know there was already an accepted answer for this, but I thought I'd post the technique in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Can't understand why this didn't get more points, the best answer until now !!! Dude, great job, much better then using the template tags and this the only MVC solution i crossed until now and working great and fast, GREAT JOB !!!

Comment: I really like this. Unfortunately, my tree structure is displayed in tables, so I needed something like `<div style="margin-left: %d * level">...`. So I ditched `'in'` and `'out'` entries and added attribute helpers with css stuff to objects itself.

Comment: this is awesome

Answer (score 3):

These are great answers but I consolidated a bit and put it on the actual model.

```
class RecursiveThing(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', blank=True, null=True)

    def as_tree(self):
        children = list(self.children.all())
        branch = bool(children)
        yield branch, self
        for child in children:
            for next in child.as_tree():
                yield next
        yield branch, None
```

And then in your template:

```
<ul>
    {% for thing in things %}
        {% for branch, obj in thing.as_tree %}
            {% if obj %}
                <li>{{ obj.name }}
                {% if branch %}
                    <ul>
                {% else %}
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% if branch %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: your answer works, but in template it shows parents and their children, but lower, it shows the same children, but as parents((( how to fix it?

Comment: What should I include in view.py

Comment: Please answer this one, what should I include in views.py

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

All you have to do in your view is get all objects:

```
people = Person.objects.all()
```

Then in your template :

```
{% for person in people %}
  <li>- {{person.name}} </li>
  {% for child in person.children.all %}
     <ul>* {{child.nom}} </ul>
  {% endfor %}
 </li>          
{% endfor %}
```